# Externally set default argument of a function from a package

Tags: r, arguments, config, default, r-package

I am building a package with functions that have default arguments. I would like to find a clean way to set the values of the default arguments once the function has been imported.

My first attempt was to set the default values to unknown objects (within the package). Then when I load the package, I would have a external script that would assign a value to the unknown objects.

But it does not seem very clean since I am compiling a function with an unknown object.

My issue is that I will need other people to use the functions, and since they have many arguments I want to keep the code as concise as possible. And many arguments can be set by a configuration script before running the program.

So, for instance, I define in my package:

```
function_try <- function(x = VAL){
return(x)
}
```

I compile the package and load it, and then I have an external script that does (or reading from a config file)

```
VAL <- "hello"
```

And then a user of the function can just run

```
function_try()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `options` for that. So your function looks like:

```
function_try <- function(x = getOption("mypackage.default.value")) x
```

In your external script you make sure that the option value is set:

```
options(mypackage.default.value = "hello")
```

IMHO that is a clean solution, because anybody reading your function will see at first sight that a certain options value is used as a default and has also a clear understanding of how to overwrite this value if needed.

I would also define a fall back value in your library `onLoad` to make sure that the value is defined in the first place. You can then even react in your functions to this fallback value and issue a meaningful warning if the function realizes that the the external script did for whatever reason not provide a new value.

Comment: I am then wondering if I could use the `config` package and have the configuration values in a YAML file, which might be more readable than a script that calls `options()` many times. Then would it be clean to define `function_try <- function(x = config::get("value"))`?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you want to add a new dependency to your library go for `config` as it provides additional benefits. However, you do not need to call `options` several times though. I would define a `list/vector`: `mypackage.defaults = list(<all your defaults>)` and store this one in the options. Your function signature would then look like this: `function(x = getOption("mypackage.defaults")$default1)`